# Calculate difference between multiple rows by a group in R

Tags: r, group-by, diff, rows

I have a data frame like this (with more observations and code variable than in this example):

```
  code  tmp     wek   sbd
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 abc01 T1        1  7.83
 2 abc01 T1        1  7.83
 3 abc01 T1        2  8.5 
 4 abc01 T1        2  8.5 
 5 abc01 T1        1  7.83
 6 abc01 T1        1  7.83
 7 abc01 T1        1  7.83
 8 abc01 T1        1  7.83
 9 abc01 T1        1  7.83
10 abc01 T2        1  7.56
11 abc01 T2        1  7.56
12 abc01 T2        2  7.22
13 abc01 T2        2  7.22
14 abc01 T2        1  7.56
15 abc01 T2        1  7.56
16 abc01 T2        1  7.56
17 abc01 T2        1  7.56
18 abc01 T2        1  7.56
```

Now I want to calculate a new variable that gives the difference of variable sbd between wek = 1 and wek = 2 by code and tmp variable.

So far I just found functions that give me the difference of consecutive rows, but this does not fit in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `match` to get the corresponding `sbd` value at `wk` 1 and 2.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(code, tmp) %>%
  summarise(diff = sbd[match(1, wek)] - sbd[match(2, wek)])

#  code  tmp    diff
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 abc01 T1    -0.67
#2 abc01 T2     0.34
```

If you want to add a new column in the dataframe keeping the rows same, use `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(code = c("abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01", 
"abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01", 
"abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01", "abc01"), tmp = c("T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2"), wek = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), sbd = c(7.83, 
7.83, 8.5, 8.5, 7.83, 7.83, 7.83, 7.83, 7.83, 7.56, 7.56, 7.22, 
7.22, 7.56, 7.56, 7.56, 7.56, 7.56)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: I tried it with the `mutate` function, because I want to keep my rows. But when I run the code, the new variable has the same value (-0.67) for all observations

Comment: You might have loaded `plyr` along with `dplyr`. Use `dplyr::mutate` to specifically call `mutate` function from `dplyr`.

Comment: Oh yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `distinct` may work

```
df %>%
  group_by(code, tmp) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  summarise(diff = diff(sbd))

  code  tmp    diff
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 abc01 T1     0.67
2 abc01 T2    -0.34
```